# Safari 8 Only CSS Animation Issue

Tags: css, safari, css-animations

I have a css animation kick in on hover for my buttons which work fine in every browser but safari 8 and I can't figure this out.

I'm using a auto vendor prefixer so there's no prefixes here.

The animations used to work fine until I upgraded to Safari 8

```
/* HOVER EFFECTS */
@keyframes push {
0% {transform: scale(1)}
50% {transform: scale(0.95)}
100% {transform: scale(1)}
}

.push {
display: inline-block;
transform: translateZ(0);
-webkit-font-smoothing:subpixel-antialiased
}
.push:hover, .push:focus, .push:active {
animation-name: push;
animation-duration: 0.3s;
animation-timing-function: linear;
animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

Anyone have a clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Witch auto prefixer are you using?
Works for me this peace of code with the corrects vendor prefix.
I'm using Safary *Version 8.0.4 (10600.4.10.7)*

Here my stipped:

```
@-webkit-keyframes push {
    0 % {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1)
    }
    50 % {
        -webkit-transform: scale(0.95)
    }
    100 % {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1)
    }
}
.push {
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -webkit-font-smoothing: subpixel-antialiased;
}
.push: hover, .push: focus, .push: active {
    -webkit-animation-name: push;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.3 s; 
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear; 
    -webkit-animation-iteratio-count: 1;
}
```

Comment: http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/.  I'm gonna try and add the webkit stuff in manually and see what happens

Comment: still doesn't work:                                                                              .push:hover, .push:focus, .push:active {
  animation-name: push;
  -webkit-animation-name: push;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

Comment: Try with mine:
@-webkit-keyframes push {
0% {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}
50% {-webkit-transform: scale(0.95)}
100% {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}
}

.push {
display: inline-block;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
-webkit-font-smoothing:subpixel-antialiased
}
.push:hover, .push:focus, .push:active {
-webkit-animation-name: push;
-webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

Comment: Can you edit the answer to merge the information from the comments please?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. (Doesn't work on iOS 8.1) - iOS Safari does not handle animation-delay very well.
Also, there's NO guarantee that the animation will start *exactly* after its given value.

So, avoid using `animation-duration` / `animation-delay` and instead set custom keyframes for each `element`, (as obsolete as this may seem) it works.

Write out each animation in full (instead of separating `animation-name`,
`animation-duration`, etc.) because under available polyfill(s), Safari does not recognize those specific properties properly, and treats them as `-webkit-animation`, and overrides the other animation rules!