# CSS: safari animation issue

Tags: css, button, webkit, transform

before posting, I have read:

- [Safari 8 Only CSS Animation Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29499562/safari-8-only-css-animation-issue)

Alright, I am building a css button, some issue only occurs in Safari.

- if you run the snippets in Chrome, it works exactly what I expect.
- if you run this in Safari, the span effect doesn't work well.

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: linear-gradient(-30deg,#1ec4e9 0%,#673ab7 50%,#262626 50%,#607d8b 100%);
}

a{
  position: relative;
  padding: 25px 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

a::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
}

a::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg,transparent,rgba(255,255,255,.4),transparent);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

a:hover::after{
  left: 100%;
}

a span{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

a span:nth-child(1){
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background: #fff;
}

a:hover span:nth-child(1){
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

a span:nth-child(3){
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background: #fff;
}

a:hover span:nth-child(3){
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <a href='#'>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    Button
  </a>

</body>
</html>
```

I have tried to add browser support such as:

```
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
```

but it still doesn't work. Could someone offers some suggestions, I want Safari to give the same result as chrome.

---

## UPDATE

This must be a priority issue since I tried:

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: linear-gradient(-30deg,#1ec4e9 0%,#673ab7 50%,#262626 50%,#607d8b 100%);
}

a{
  position: relative;
  padding: 25px 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

a::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
}

a::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg,transparent,rgba(255,255,255,.4),transparent);
  -webkit-transition: 2s;
}

a:hover::after{
  left: 100%;
}

a span{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: 2s ease;
}

a span:nth-child(1){
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background: #fff;
}

a:hover span:nth-child(1){
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <a href='#'>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    Button
  </a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Safari Version: Version 13.1.2 (15609.3.5.1.3)

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=transform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it as you made it for your shadow (in `::after`), use `left` or `right`:

```
a:hover span:nth-child(1){
  width: 100%;
  /*-webkit-transform: translateX(100%);*/
  left:100%;
}

a:hover span:nth-child(3){
  width: 100%;
  /*transform: translateX(-100%);*/
  right: 100%;
}
```

### Demo (1):

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: linear-gradient(-30deg,#1ec4e9 0%,#673ab7 50%,#262626 50%,#607d8b 100%);
}

a{
  position: relative;
  padding: 25px 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

a::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
}

a::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg,transparent,rgba(255,255,255,.4),transparent);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

a:hover::after{
  left: 100%;
}

a span{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

a span:nth-child(1){
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background: #fff;
}

a:hover span:nth-child(1){
  width: 100%;
  /*transform: translateX(100%);*/
  left: 100%;
}

a span:nth-child(3){
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background: #fff;
}

a:hover span:nth-child(3){
  width: 100%;
  /*transform: translateX(-100%);*/
  right: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <a href='#'>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    Button
  </a>

</body>
</html>
```

### DEMO (update):

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: linear-gradient(-30deg,#1ec4e9 0%,#673ab7 50%,#262626 50%,#607d8b 100%);
}

a{
  position: relative;
  padding: 25px 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

a::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
}

a::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg,transparent,rgba(255,255,255,.4),transparent);
  -webkit-transition: 2s;
}

a:hover::after{
  left: 100%;
}

a span{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: 2s ease;
}

a span:nth-child(1){
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 1px;
  background: #fff;
}

a:hover span:nth-child(1){
  width: 100%;
  /*-webkit-transform: translateX(100%);*/
  left:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <a href='#'>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    Button
  </a>

</body>
</html>
```